# Issues with Native React

Tags: javascript, android, ubuntu, android-emulator, react-native

I’m new here in stackoverflow and i’m new in programming too, my problem is this:

I'm starting to learn react native, my OS is Linux (Ubuntu), and my smartphone is Android (LG G3), I followed all the steps:

1: Install the JDK,  Android Studio, Watchman, Node, the React Native Command Line Interface, 
Everything!

2: So, I’m trying run the react native on my device.

3: Appear some errors.

4: On my smartphone, shows this:

5: [Screenshot SmartPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08BEo.png)

6: My questions, what can I be doing  wrong ? You know how run in a emulator? (I have the Genymotion, but I don't know use them). Please I need help!
Thanks!

7: I put the IP on my smartphone and the error changed:

8: [Screenshot smartphone 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xweo0.png)

9: I'm sorry for the ignorance, how I said, I don't have much knowledge.

10: Anyone know what is this error?

Answer (score 1):

Running on a device in dev-mode differs from the emulator,

you should check out this page to set it up:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

The problem you have, is that your device cannot connect to the dev-server, you have to configure the correct IP Address and so on..

The same is on iOS